# Cisco ASA 5540 multi-WAN and QoS setup

Tags: cisco, qos, wide-area-network

What is the best way to configure the following on a Cisco ASA 5540?

- I have 2 WAN lines, I need mail (tcp 25) on the one and all other traffic on the second WAN line.
- On the second WAN line I need to prioritize traffic for some external websites.

I am quite lost in the stacks of documents from Cisco and I have not configured this before.
Any help thanks.

Comment: Have a budget for this? What type of WAN links are they?

Comment: Currently two 10Mb ADSL lines. No budget I will have to do this myself with the equipment currently on site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer is simple. Cisco ASA devices are not designed to be routers but rather security appliances. Thus it cannot handle multiple gateways and routes.

Comment: I'm sorry but you're completely mistaken... Cisco ASAs handle both static and dynamic routing with no problem; that means they can handle multiple gateways.